# What's the state of the art way to detect / change audio pitch?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, pitch

Detecting pitch: It seems that selecting the modal frequency in the frequency spectrum is too simple an algorithm for reliable results.

For detecting, and changing, the pitch of a note, what are the best / fastest algorithms?

Comment: Do you know anything about the pitch? If you are detecting between only a few known frequencies, you can use the [Goertzel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm). If you don't know the frequencies, a peak of the FFT is probably the best.

Comment: @Ash what about the harmonics?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  There's the ASDF and AMDF algorithms that are in the question that I've marked as duplicate. Please review that question and its answers. If that doesn't help, feel free to ping me here and I'll reopen, but you'll also need to refine your question (by editing it).